# SassError while customizing Bootstrap css in React

Tags: css, reactjs, sass, react-bootstrap

I am trying to override some of bootstrap styling in my React project, using sass. However, I am getting an error. Below is the custom.scss file, and the error that I am getting during compilation.

custom.scss

```
code {
    background:#F8F8FF;
    border:black dashed 1px;
    padding:6px;
}​

// Import Bootstrap and its default variables
@use '~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap.scss';
```

Complete error:

```
./src/scss/custom.scss (./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--5-oneOf-6-1!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src??postcss!./node_modules/resolve-url-loader??ref--5-oneOf-6-3!./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--5-oneOf-6-4!./src/scss/custom.scss)

SassError: expected "{".
  ╷
9 │ @use '~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap.scss';
  │                                      ^
```

Any advice on how to get rid of this error would be appreciated.

EDIT:

Additional info:
I am getting `{ expected scss(css-lcurlyexpected)` problem in VSCode under @use.

Comment: To import stylesheets, you use the @import keyword

Comment: it is going to be replaced by @use. Reference: https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/import

Comment: In that case, are you using a version of sass that doesn't support @use but supports @import?

Comment: No, I am using the latest version. In any case, replacing \@use with \@import also reproduces the same error.

Comment: Try to import  on first line in custom.css 

@use '~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap.scss';